# Microsoft.Phone assembly is missing in Windows Phone 8 app project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am writing a Windows Phone 8 app. I am trying to create a secondary tile by following documentation. I am trying to create a [IconicTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.iconictiledata) however for some reasosn project can't find the reference to Microsoft.Phone.

Any ideas why is that happening, or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

P.S. I have Widnows Phone SDK 8.1

Comment: What's the reference its asking for?

Comment: It asking for Microsoft.Phone.Shell

Comment: Can't you try adding it within your reference? Refernce > Add New Reference > Browse for the .dll within the location you have the SDK

Comment: I would believe it should be part of the framework and you shouldn't need to reference it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**
If you are creating a WinRt app (which you should going forward as Silverlight won't be supported in future), you should use `SecondaryTile` instead of IconicTile see documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.ui.startscreen.secondarytile).

**Long answer:**
As it turns out there are multiple SDKs:

- Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight)
- Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight)
- Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT)

So to start with what is confusing for me is the name of new OS (8.1), it should have been at least 8.5 or even 9, at least from the dev perspective, as there are so many changes to the SDK.

So after some reasearch, this is how I understand the new WP world:

So **Windows Phone 8 (Silverligt)** is the old SDK. This is hosted inside silverlight container and phone exposes a set of APIs which you can consume from your silverlight app. So this is history now.

Next **Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight)** - the reason why this version exists is so devs can easily port their app to WP 8.1 without a need to rewrite it completely, but going forward it will be depricated.

And finally **Windows Phone 8.1** this is what is also known as Universal apps. As it uses native XAML rendering and native API calls, which are pretty much the same between Windows and Windows Phone now.

So why things are confusing is because now you have to Windows Phone 8.1 versions. And I haven't found any clarification anywhere on MS website. Also note that if documentation sates Widnows Phone 8.1, it means non Silverlight version.

And my mistakes was using an assemly which was Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight instead of Windows Phone 8.1. So That's why I suggest to download a sample and check the new SDK. As answers on the web might relate to both Widnows Phone 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight.

Hence my original answer:

I ended up download a bunch of sample projects from MSDN which target Windows Phone 8.1 and following the [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-81-samples-08631ca7). I think this is a correct url..

I found that following the example is much easier than googling, because whenever you google it comes back with a SO answer or link to MSDN, but then you have to figure out if it's Windows Phone 8.1 Store App or other version.

A great resource to see the difference between [namespaces between Windows Phone 8.1 and WP 8.1 Silverlight.](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/Media/DiffLists/Windows%20Phone%208.1%20(Silverlight)-vs-Windows%20Phone%208.1.html)

Comment: So what steps did you take to resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Can you explain what the solution was instead of simply linking to a tutorial page?

Comment: The namespace appears to be related to the type of store app that the user creates (i.e. Silverlight or WinRT)The following link explains the issue in detail: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/66ccf8f6-8459-451b-90d1-2e0d1afabfbc/universal-app-in-vs2013-rc2-problem-accessing-wp-specific-assemblies-in-the-universalwindowsphone?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: I have tried to explain the whole story in a bit more details. Let me know if you have problems and I will try to update my answer.